# What data type should the unique IDs be in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm about to LOAD some random data into Neo4j.  Documentation says that the `IDs must be unique`.  Does the data type of unique identifier matter?  For e.g. can I have a unique string as an identifier instead of a (integer) number?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have unique Strings instead on numbers! afaik, any valid data type, even Point